# Listening to microphone from a website

Tags: asp.net, html

Well question can be general but we would like to understand it more deeply . sorry for not understanding basic stuff, i do other software .
We would like to set owr website, so that when user is open it, he will be asked to let the url open his `microphone` on his `pc/mac` .
I wonder also if `Apples mac's` will allowed that .
Than ,that website will have to listen to the microphone to analyze the data (in the `client` side= not sending it to `server` , processing software is in the client side ) .

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to just connect to the Microphone and get the file then you can try HTML5 tag as:

```
<input type="file" accept="Audio/*" capture />
```

This will request for permission to access the Microphone from the user's system. Once permission is granted you can continue the work, to either save it, or upload it, or what so ever

#### Reference:

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/09/Live-Web-Audio-Input-Enabled